# Can the length of a module be seen as a specific Krull-dimension?

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, modules

For an arbitrary unital, commutative ring $R$ and a corresponding unital $R$-module $M$, does there exist a topology on $M$ s.t. the induced Krull-dimension of $M$ coincides with it's length as a $R$-module?

Now more generally, can the length of a module be derived from Krull dimension somehow?
Eg., is something similar possible as with $\text{dim}\left(R\right)=\text{dim}\left(\text{Spec}\left(R\right)\right)$ (using Zariski)?

Or does it eg. fail at constructing useful topologies on an arbitrary module already?

Edit: Obviously, the definition of length may be used in the construction of the topology. Is it clear what I want?

Comment: Typically you define [the Krull dimension purely algebraically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension#Krull_dimension_of_a_module). There's no need to refer to any topology at all. And no, Krull dimension and length don't seem to be related.

Comment: @freakish I know, the usual definition is dim(R)=length(Spec(R))=dim(Spec(R)), by using the Zarisiki topology., right?
mm okay. Yeah I know the question is somehow artificial and seems unnecessary, I just wondered. :) Thx.

Comment: Yes, the Krull dimension can be expressed via Zariski topology. But if you change topology then you don't get Krull dimension. By changing topology you can get pretty much any number you want (assuming Spec(R) is big enough). So the topological aspect of your question isn't really valid.

Comment: Yeah, it also seams to me that the answer would rather give me a better understanding of how powerful topology is, I also can't seam to see any practical use. Also thx, I added Zariski to the question.

Comment: Oh and yes thx, u helped me to remember something else: since they don't seem related, I would expect there to be an easy finite counterexample?!

Comment: Take any ring $R$ and consider $M=R^n$. Then the annihilator of $M$ is trivial, hence the Krull dimension of $M$ equals to the Krull dimension of $R$. So say $R=k$ is a field. Then the Krull dimension of $k^n$ is $0$ while length of $k^n$ is $n$. The only clear relationship is that the Krull dimension is at most the length. But I'm pretty sure that there's a counterexample for any such pair of numbers.

Comment: AH!! I totally forgot that there is a non-topological usual Krull dimension for modules!